# Algorithm - minimal number of bits to distinguish a set of given binary numbers

Tags: algorithm

Say that we are given `K` different binary numbers, each with length `N` (`N` can be large). Is there an efficient algorithm to determine the minimal number of bits it needs to distinguish these numbers from each other?

For example:

Given `110` and `011`, we only have to check the first (or the last) bit to distinguish them, so the minimal number is `1`.

Given `1000`, `0100`, `0010` and `0001`, we need to check at least three bits to distinguish, so the minimal number is `3`.

Given `0000`, `0100`, `1000` and `1100`, we only have to check the first two bits, so the minimal number is `2`.

Follow-up: output the corresponding indexes to be checked.

---

Edit: Assuming these binary numbers are represented as `a1[0,1,…,N-1]`, …, `aK[0,1,…,N-1]`. This problem is equivalent to finding the minimal subsequence `[i,j,…,m]` of `[0,1,…,N-1]` so that `a1[i,j,…,m]`, …, `aK[i,j,…,m]` are different numbers.

Comment: Can you take *arbitraty* bits into account, or everytime you have to select the *first* bits?

Comment: This problem is [NP-complete](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/HyafilRivest-ConstructingOptimalBinaryDecisionTreesIsNPComplete.pdf).

Comment: @TamasHegedus Arbitrary bits. Note these binary numbers are guaranteed to be different.

Comment: @augurar it's not quite the same problem. This one talks about the smallest set of bits you *might* need to check and the paper talks about the smallest number of checks to be made. {000 001 100 110} Here you only need 2 checks but you may need to check any of the 3 bits.

Comment: @n.m. The binary numbers are assumed to be inputted by the user, so for your example, we only need to check the first 2 bits. For other input, we might need to check 3 bits.

Comment: @NGY yes sorry this is a bad example.

Comment: @NGY Do you have a performance requirement (space or/and time) ?

Comment: @T.Claverie Any solution other than the brute force one is helpful. The faster, the better.

Comment: @NGY Did you find the better solution yet?

Comment: @krsoni No. According to the answers and comments, a feasible polynomial time solution is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The [Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) is defined in terms of a set *U*, and a set *S* of subsets of *U*. Each element in *U* must be covered by (at least) one of the sets in *S*.

If you can solve Set Cover, you can solve this problem as well. Suppose you build a set *U* whose each entry, *u<sub>i, j</sub>* (where *i < j*), corresponds to the pairs *(i, j)* and *(j, i)* of your *k* numbers (hence *|U| = k (k - 1) /2*). Now build *n* sets, *S<sub>1</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>*, corresponding to the *n* possible bit positions. Set *S<sub>j</sub>* is the subset of all the elements corresponding to pairs position *j* differentiates. That is, if numbers *k, l* are different in position *j*, then set *u<sub>k, l</sub> ∈ S<sub>j</sub>*.

As such, the [simple greedy algorithm for set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm), can give you an bounded approximation of the minimal number of bits. Unfortunately, it will not give you the *minimal* number of bits. As noted by @augurar in the comments, this problem is NP-Hard by reduction, and, as such, probably does not have a feasible exact optimal algorithm.

Comment: That this problem is reducible to Set Cover is good for showing that you can apply set cover algorithms to solving it. You would need reduction from an NP-hard problem to this problem, the other way round, to show that this one is NP-hard, and therefore is unlikely to have an exact polynomial time solution.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You are absolutely correct. However, as I tried to say in the answer, once you see the construction for one direction, it's easy to reverse it to reduce the problem in the other direction.

Comment: Maybe add "Reduction from Set Cover" to outline the reduction?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's a good suggestion, thanks. There's a know NP-Hard reduction in the comments, to which I've now referred. This answer's main point, therefore, is that the trivial greedy SC algorithm will work here as well, so I've retained that part.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Misunderstood the question, scheme not working.

What you want to do is some kind of XOR. But not simply xoring all numbers altogether. But if you could produce a binary number which has 1 when it's a relevant bit, and 0 if the bit is irrelevant. An irrelevant bit is a bit that has always the same value no matter what the numbers are: you do not need it to differentiate the numbers. For example:

```
11001
01001
10101
-----
11100
```

First and second bit are irrelevant because they always have the same value.

**How to do it**

For this you need to compute two binary numbers from your set. The first one is a logical OR between all of the numbers. The bits that are still 0 are irrelevant, it's easy to see. The second number is a logical AND on all of the numbers of the set. The bits that are left to 1 are irrelevant, it's also easy to see. Now, XOR those two numbers together. That's your result. Applied on the previous example:

```
11001 | 01001 | 10101 = 11101
11001 & 01001 & 10101 = 00001
11101 ^ 00001 = 11100 // Here is your result, the first 3 bits are relevant
```

Comment: The problem is you might be able to choose a subset of the relevant bits.  For instance if the numbers are `111` and `000` then all three bits are potentially relevant but you only need to check one of them.

Comment: Damn, it's tougher than it seems. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @T.Claverie I think there's a mistake in `xor`. `11101 ^ 00001 = 00011` should be `11101 ^ 00001 = 11100` and then the invert won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Not working. See comments.

This question can be solved using a Trie.

All you need to do is to represent the binary numbers in form of a Trie.

Then *count the number of distinct levels with at least one node with out-degree 2*.

[image].

Each level represent the same bit position. Therefore you've to choose either 1 of it.

This works because at each *level* you are basically making a decision and identifying different set of strings.

As in the image, there are 3 levels with at least 1 node of out degree 2. And that's your answer.

It's easy enough from here on to output the indices checked.

Another example,to highlight why we are counting the level instead of nodes.

000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111

[image]

Answer is 3 bits.

Comment: Can you verify whether your approach works for 4 numbers - 000, 011, 101, 111? These numbers can be identified using the first two bits, but constructing a trie will give 3 nodes with out-degree 2.

Comment: I think the answer should be determining _the number of distinct levels_ of the trie where at least one node has out-degree of 2.

Comment: @nisargshah95 Thank you. That was mighty ignorant of me. You are absolutely correct, because each level represents the same bit position, so it doesn't make any sense to count all the nodes present on that level. Thanks, up-voted you and edited.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it even this solution is wrong :P. Consider 0000000, 1000001, 1100010, 1110011, 1111100.

Comment: Maybe we need to look both ways to find the answer? Constructing 2 tries. One trie with all the original strings and another trie with reverse of the original strings. Answer would be minimum of those.
I'm counting on you to find a counter case :P

Answer (score 0):

The solution must lie in range `[log2(K), K-1]`. log2(K) being the best case. So a brute force method might be to iterate this range taking every possible combination of bits for each iteration until it distinguish all the K strings. But the time complexity might be exponential.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem when creating a hash map algorithm ( https://github.com/robert-king/my-hash-map )

My solution was to use linear integer programming. let Xi be 1 if the ith bit is important otherwise zero. Then for each pair of numbers A and B having ith bits Ai and Bi, we require Sum(Xi, Ai != Bi) >= 1, So that we can distinguish between A and B. The objective function is to minimise Sum(Xi), thus minimising the number of bits.

Performance: For up to 100 random numbers, it was taking a second. for 150 random numbers, it was taking 10-20 seconds. (Can't remember if they were 32 bit or 64 bit numbers).

```
  package algorithms

import (
    "github.com/draffensperger/golp"
    "fmt"
)

const numOnes = uint64(19)
const ones = uint64(1 << numOnes - 1)

func diffBit(a, b, i uint64) bool {
    return (a >> i) & 1 != (b >> i) & 1
}

func differentBits(a, b uint64) (ints []uint64) {
    if a < b {
        a,b = b,a
    }
    for i := uint64(0); a >> i > 0; i++ {
        if diffBit(a, b, i) {
            ints = append(ints, i)
        }
    }
    return ints
}

func checkBitsDistinguishNums(nums []uint64, bits []uint16) bool {
    offsets := make(map[uint16]bool)
    for _, num := range nums {
        offset := bitScore(num, bits)
        _, ok := offsets[offset]
        if ok {
            return false
        }
        offsets[offset] = true
    }
    return true
}

func minimumDistinguishingBits(nums []uint64) (bits []uint16) {
    if len(nums) == 1 {
        return bits
    }

    var likelySolutions = [][]uint16{
        []uint16{0},
        []uint16{1},
        []uint16{2},
        []uint16{3},
        []uint16{4},
        []uint16{0,1},
        []uint16{0,2},
        []uint16{5},
        []uint16{1,2},
        []uint16{0,3},
        []uint16{6},
        []uint16{7},
        []uint16{8},
        []uint16{0,4},
        []uint16{1,3},
        []uint16{1,4},
        []uint16{2,3},
        []uint16{0,5},
        []uint16{2,4},
        []uint16{1,5},
        []uint16{0,1,2},
        []uint16{0,1,3},
        []uint16{2,5},
        []uint16{0,6},
        []uint16{0,7},
        []uint16{9},
        []uint16{0,2,3},
        []uint16{2,6},
        []uint16{1,7},
        []uint16{1,6},
        []uint16{3,5},
        []uint16{2,7},
        []uint16{10},
        []uint16{1,3,8},
        []uint16{4,7},
        []uint16{3,6},
        []uint16{0,2,11},
        []uint16{3,8},
        []uint16{1,2,5},
        []uint16{0,3,4},
        []uint16{0,1,12},
        []uint16{0,1,2,5},
        []uint16{4,6},
        []uint16{3,4},
        []uint16{0,10},
        []uint16{0,8},
        []uint16{0,1,4},
        []uint16{11},
        []uint16{1,2,3},
        []uint16{0,2,4},
        []uint16{1,2,9},
        []uint16{3,12},
    }

    for _, likelySolution := range likelySolutions {
        if checkBitsDistinguishNums(nums, likelySolution) {
            return likelySolution
        }
    }

    var equations [][]golp.Entry
    maxDiffBit := uint64(0)
    for i := range nums {
        for j := 0; j < i; j++ {
            var equation []golp.Entry
            for _, bit := range differentBits(nums[i], nums[j]) {
                if bit > maxDiffBit {
                    maxDiffBit = bit
                }
                equation = append(equation, golp.Entry{int(bit), 1})
            }
            equations = append(equations, equation)
        }
    }
    lp := golp.NewLP(0, int(maxDiffBit)+1)
    for _, equation := range equations {
        lp.AddConstraintSparse(equation, golp.GE, 1)
    }
    var objFn []float64
    for i := 0; i <= int(maxDiffBit); i++ {
        lp.SetInt(i, true)
        objFn = append(objFn, float64(i))
    }
    lp.SetObjFn(objFn)
    lp.Solve()
    for i, bit := range lp.Variables() {
        if bit == 1 {
            bits = append(bits, uint16(i))
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Likely solution not found but found ", bits)

    return bits
}
```